# paramiko.connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth_timeout'

Tags: python, paramiko

## Trying to run below code:

```
try:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(device, username='username', password='password', look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False, timeout=None, auth_timeout=60.0 )
    remote_conn = ssh.invoke_shell()
    output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
    print("connection established to %s" % device)
except IOError as error:
    print("connecting to device %s failed." % device)
    print error
except paramiko.AuthenticationException as error:
    print("connecting to device %s failed." % device)
    print error 
except Exception as error:
    print("connecting to device %s failed." % device)
    print error
```

## getting below mentioned error:

connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth_timeout'

## Referrence:

http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html

Comment: Have you found an answer?